# What kind of transformation does each matrix determine?

Tags: matrices

I have been given 5 matrices, been asked 'What kind of transformation does each matrix determine?', to multiply them and to 'Explain how the transformations determined by each matrix in the pair are related to each other'.

Each matrix gives me binary answers (0 1, 1 0 etc, they are 2v2 matrices).

How do i answer this -> What kind of transformation does each matrix determine?

I know there is a name when the transformations form those 0 1 answers but i'm not sure what its called, and i'm guessing that's the answer? Also how is each matrix in the pair related to each other?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided the original question, as it was asked.

Comment: I would, but everyone on here is butthurt about posting pictures....i'm pretty sure its the identity matrix btw

Comment: Post the picture. People don't like it when you *just* post the picture (without any other explanation), but posting pictures is okay.  What you should *really* be doing is [formatting your math correctly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360), but at least the picture will get things moving in the right direction.

Comment: Also, butthurt?  This isn't reddit.

Comment: If you're looking at the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
then no, that isn't the identity matrix.